# Повторное использование той же переменной по ссылке в цикле foreach заменяет значение в другом массиве, почему?

Tags: php

Я в недоумении. Подскажите в чем загвоздка.

Пытаюсь правильно менять значения элементов ассоциативного массива внутри цикла foreach.

Задаю начальные значения массива и вывожу на экран:

```
$arr=array(1,2);
print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Затем в цикле задаю элементам массива новые значения. Знак "&" использую для того, чтобы значения эти можно было менять внутри цикла:

```
foreach ($arr as $k => &$v) $v = $k*2;
```

Проверяю:

```
print_r($arr);
```

Получаю то что ожидал:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
)
```

А вот дальше мне вообще не понятно что происходит. Два варианта (меняется последовательность строк):

1) Первый вариант действий:

```
foreach ($arr as $k => &$v) echo " [$k] => $v".PHP_EOL;
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) echo " [$k] => $v".PHP_EOL;
```

Результат:

```
 [0] => 0
 [1] => 2
 [0] => 0
 [1] => 0
```

Первый цикл с использованием "&" выводит то, что мне нужно. А второй цикл выводит нули. Почему?

2) Второй  вариант действий (вместо первого), еще более странный (меняем только последовательность циклов):

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) echo " [$k] => $v".PHP_EOL;
foreach($arr as $k=>&$v) echo " [$k] => $v".PHP_EOL;
```

Получаем:

```
 [0] => 0
 [1] => 0
 [0] => 0
 [1] => 0
```

O_o ...

То, что & используется как указатель на переменную, чтобы иметь возможность работать не с копией массива, а реальными значениями элементов в цикле foreach - понятно. Непонятно, почему вывод print_r отличается от выводов в цикле foreach.

И почему результаты выводов foreach, когда я меняю местами две строки - разные. Вроде бы операций присвоения в выводе я не использовал...

P.S. PHP Version 7.0.33-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После окончания цикла `$v` всё ещё ссылается на последний элемент массива, а следующий цикл повторно использует эту переменную для присвоения. Пример такого повторного использования:

```php
<?php

$arr = [0, 1];

foreach ($arr as $k => &$v) {
    echo " [$k] => $v\n";
}

$v = 5;

var_dump($arr[1]);
```

[Выведет](https://3v4l.org/OmkEW) `int(5)`, что ещё одна причина почему лучше не менять значения по ссылке внутри цикла. При смене значений по ключу никаких таких неожиданных эффектов нет.

Не так страшна эта проблема если вы только пишете программу. Гораздо более неприятные последствия могут быть если смена значения по ссылке из цикла добавляется где-нибудь в середине большой старой программы без достаточного покрытия тестами. Тут жди беды и головной боли при отладке, когда неожиданные значения вылезают в неожиданных местах без видимой  причины. Конечно, если вы знаете об этой опасности, то это первая вещь, которую вы будете искать по коду, но и верно что, если вы знаете об этом, то и добавлять не будете без обертывания этой операции функцией или чего-то такого.

Comment: Благодарю. Как я понял вот это   foreach  ($arr as $k => &$v) $v = $k*2; надо переписать вот так foreach ($arr as $k => $v) $arr[$k] = $k*2;

Comment: Да, верно, так можно переписать